# Why does git complain about an empty repository or a folder with existing files?

Tags: git, bitbucket

In BitBucket if I try and create a repository into an existing folder I get an error complaining that it is not an empty directory. If I go into an empty folder it complains that it is an empty folder.

What are the steps involved in adding an existing project already in development to a repo using Git and BitBucket?

The quick-start steps are obviously not quite right on the BitBucket page:

```
$ git clone git@bitbucket.org:myname/myproject.git
...
$ git pull                  # to fetch changes
$ git push -u origin master # to push changes for the first time
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of cloning, you have to:

```
git init .   # in your project repo
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:myname/myproject.git
git push -u origin master  # assuming it is a newly created repo on BitBucket
```